# Xtext error: Registered resource factory is needed

Tags: java, eclipse, uri, xtext

I have an application that accepts a file as an input. 
Since the files are located in different location, the path will be relative to the .jar location.

Example: 
D:\Test\JAVA_App\Exe is where that tester.jar is placed.
So when ran in the windows command line, I do this:
tester.jar D:\Test\JAVA_App\Exe....\testcase1.txt

To process the file, my code is calling ResourceSet from org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet.
This is the code I have:

```
ResourceSet set = resourceSetProvider.get()
Resource resource = set.getResource(URI.createURI(<inputted path of file>))
```

I found out that the "registered resource factory is needed" error is not caused by an incorrect path (I can open it if I run the whole path in the commandline), but because of the "..\" in between. If I use "....\testcase1.txt" only, it works fine. But if it has the "D:\" in the beginning with "..\" in between, the error occurs.

Is there another way to use "D:\Test\JAVA_App\Exe....\testcase1.txt" in xtext?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that the D: is interpreted as a scheme. Try using 'URI.createFileURI()' instead.

Comment: This works for me. But createFileURI is giving me a different path as compared to the one I input. This only happens if the path is around 190 characters in length.

Example:
`D:\01_Work\01_Testcases\Testcases_01\ToolSet\Modulars\TC\TESTS\TESTS_V2\SRC\TXT..\DOC\ToolUsages\NormalUser\CombinedNotifications\UnregisteredUsersX_**p**rio_199\Normal_user_daytime_133_to_134.txt`
The path read by getResource is:
`D:\01_Work\01_Testcases\Testcases_01\ToolSet\Modulars\TC\TESTS\TESTS_V2\SRC\TXT..\DOC\ToolUsages\NormalUser\CombinedNotifications\UnregisteredUsersX_rio_199\Normal_user_daytime_133_to_134.txt`